# is it possible to show map in dompdf in laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf, sugarcrm, dompdf, suitecrm

Hello I am trying to show map in pdf but every time pdf shows me empty result. can anyone help me. If its is possible how can i do that 
Here i have tried so far:-

```
public function savepdf(Request $request){
    PDF::loadView('map-pdf')->save('images/map.pdf' ); 
    echo "saved"; die;
}
```

In map-pdf i simply show the map with marker it is successfully shown in browser but not in pdf. please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use first produce image of your map and marker and then use that image in PDF? I think you are aware that how you can get image of area on map, if not then read it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/?csw=1

Also following code can help you because it worked for me in many projects:

```
    $options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
```

Comment: follow this path:
1. get file contents from google and create local image file (use google for creating image, hopefully it will help )
2. use local image in PDF. Make sure that local image copy is valid. Local mean same server where you executing your dom pdf code.

Comment: if i want to zoom in out how can i do that